# Time Range Picker for Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-timepicker

Does anyone know anything about useful time range picker libraries that are open source? For example, the app Twilight uses some custom slider view for picking time ranges that I find very appealing (see bottom):

[image]

Is this open-source or are there similarly functional pickers? I could not find anything useful in the docs or on Android Arsenal.

Alternatively, I might build it from scratch. I was just wondering if there is not anything around yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this slider from Material Design library and implements for youself:

https://material.io/develop/android/components/sliders

ps. check the section: "Setting a LabelFormatter"

Answer (score 0):

An open source solution using a pop-up-dialog : [TimeRangePicker](https://github.com/Droppers/TimeRangePicker)